# Conectar no Cloud SQL via PHP hospedado no Compute Engine

Tags: php, servidor

Como faço para conectar em uma instância do Cloud SQL através de um arquivo php hospedado em uma VM do Compute Engine?

• Possuo uma instância MySQL no Cloud SQL chamada `bd-vendas` e nela criei um banco chamado `vendas`.

• Possuo uma VM Linux Debian criada no Compute Engine.

Obs.: Eu gostaria de fazer a conexão usando PDO

Tentei isso, mas não deu certo:

```
<?php
    function getConnection(){
        try {
          $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=999.999.999.99;dbname=vendas', 'usuario', 'senha');
          $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          return $connection;
          } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return;
        }
    }

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi alterando a string de conexão da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    function getConnection(){
        try {                                {GCSQL IPv4}                {Nome da conexao da instância}            {Nome banco}
          $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=999.999.999.99;unix_socket=/cloudsql/instance:bd-instance;charset=utf8;dbname=vendas', 'usuario', 'senha');
          $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          return $connection;
          } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return;
        }
    }

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```